# Remove elements in array from array using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I want to remove users in the `removeUser` array based on `userName` values in the `removeUser` array using lodash. Here's my input data:

```
{"users":[
{"title":"Mr", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "email":"jdoe@google.com", "userName" : "jdoe", "groups": [{"name": "Manager"}]},
{"title":"Ms", "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith","email":"asmith@google.com", "userName" : "asmith", "groups": [{"name": "Administrator"}, {"name": "Manager"}]},
{"title":"Mr", "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "email":"pjones@google.com", "userName" : "pjones", "groups": [{"name": "Administrator"}, {"name": "Manager"}]},
{"title":"Ms", "firstName":"Jenny", "lastName":"Otter","email":"jotter@google.com", "userName" : "jotter", "groups": [{"name": "Administrator"}, {"name": "Manager"}]}
]}

var removeUser = ['jdoe', 'asmith'];  //usernames of users to be removed
```

This is what I have but I need a foreach loop:

```
_remove(users, { userName: [removeUser]})
```

so that I end up with an updated `users` array along the lines of:

```
{"users":[
{"title":"Mr", "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "email":"pjones@google.com", "userName" : "pjones", "groups": [{"name": "Administrator"}, {"name": "Manager"}]},
{"title":"Ms", "firstName":"Jenny", "lastName":"Otter","email":"jotter@google.com", "userName" : "jotter", "groups": [{"name": "Administrator"}, {"name": "Manager"}]}
]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [callback as second argument](https://lodash.com/docs#remove), like so

```js
var data = {"users": [
  {"title":"Mr", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "email":"jdoe@google.com", "userName" : "jdoe", "groups": [{"name": "Manager"}]},
  {"title":"Ms", "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith","email":"asmith@google.com", "userName" : "asmith", "groups": [{"name": "Administrator"}, {"name": "Manager"}]},
  {"title":"Mr", "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "email":"pjones@google.com", "userName" : "pjones", "groups": [{"name": "Administrator"}, {"name": "Manager"}]},
  {"title":"Ms", "firstName":"Jenny", "lastName":"Otter","email":"jotter@google.com", "userName" : "jotter", "groups": [{"name": "Administrator"}, {"name": "Manager"}]}
]};

var removeUser = ['jdoe', 'asmith']; 

_.remove(data.users, function(el) {
  // if el.userName exists in removeUser return true and remove it from data.users
  return removeUser.indexOf(el.userName) >= 0;
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.9.0/lodash.js"></script>
```